# Why does GO AST Parser regenerate code with extra spaces or indents?

Tags: go, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to regenerate source code from ast of a go program. After regenerating the source code, I am trying to match that with the original source code. But the regenerated source code gives some extra spaces in some places of the code. The code is given below.

```
fs := token.NewFileSet()
f, err := parser.ParseFile(fs, filename, nil, parser.ParseComments)
if err != nil {
log.Println(err)
}
cfg := printer.Config{Mode: printer.RawFormat}
err = cfg.Fprint(&buffer, fs, f)
if err != nil {
log.Println(err)
}
source_code, err := os.ReadFile(filename)
if err != nil {
log.Println(err)
}
buffer_source_code := buffer.String()
```

Can someone help me what should I do to get the exact source code as the original from a ast?

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires this? This sounds like a case of the [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). ASTs are not meant to keep the original formatting of source code.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Decorated Syntax Tree](https://github.com/dave/dst)

The dst package enables manipulation of a Go syntax tree with high fidelity. Decorations (e.g. comments and **line spacing**) remain attached to the correct nodes as the tree is modified.